# COUNTIF across multiple sheets with dupilcate detection

Tags: google-sheets

Was hard to give this question an accurate title, so sorry if its wrong.

Anyway, given the following data...

[image: Example1]

With each sheet being a different player I need to count the number of games played in each colored room across all players.

That's easy enough with countif..

[image: Example2]

But some games have multiple players and in those cases the game would be counted multiple times using the above method.

One solution I'm trying giving each game with multiple players an ID, a random string, then checking if an ID is present and if so, only count all games with the same ID as one.

The end result should end up like this.

[image: Example3]

Despite my effort I havent been able to figure this out. Anyone have any tips on how to go about this? or if there is a better way to prevent the same game from being counted twice.

If possible I'd like to avoid using the apps-script.
Thanks.

Comment: in your sample orange games has only ID: o001. So why the result is 4? You mean, if there's no ID, then count each game?

Comment: If this logic is correct, then green counts 3: 2 times with no ID + id: g001

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Sheet 3 has 3 orange games with no idea, 3 different games plus the orange game with an ID (indicating theyre the same game), 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me answer is based on guess:

1. count each item with no ID
2. count items with same Id's as one item

Then you may go to Result_sheet and use the formula:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY({Sheet1!A:B;Sheet2!A:B;Sheet3!A:B},"select Col1, Col2 where Col2 <> ''")),"select Col1, 1");QUERY({Sheet1!A:B;Sheet2!A:B;Sheet3!A:B},"select Col1, 1 where Col1 <> '' and Col2 = ''")},"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '', Col1 '  Game Count'")
```

If you add sample file, I'll make an example with this formula.